# Install and Update plugins on a VPS Wordpress installation

Tags: plugins, ftp

I have installed Wordpress. Everything works smooth except one thing: I cannot ftp through Wordpress - meaning I cannot update or install plugins.  Using my vps root user and password doesn't work (but it works using Filezilla).
Any idea what are the steps needed to enable this feature?

Is it a permission issue, or maybe I need to create dedicated users on the VPS?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for posting the question above, I fixed it right after posting here, by following these steps I found on this site http://artofsimplicity.co.uk/wordpress-ftp-auto-upgrade-on-ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
sudo useradd wordpress
sudo passwd wordpress # set password for wordpress when prompted.
sudo usermod -g www-data wordpress
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo vi /etc/passwd # change wordpress home to be: /var/www
sudo service vsftpd restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```